# CSS style override in HTML fails

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code in my HTML:

```
<li class="img1" style="opacity:1 !important; display:block !important;">
```

but it does not get applied. Using Firebug (Inspect button, Ctrl+Shift+I), I redefine this code and it works:

[image]

Is there a way to correctly apply this in my HTML?

Comment: Create a css rule for the img1 class and put this opacity as important, if  necessary.

Comment: What exactly does "but it does not get applied" mean?

Comment: I meant, it does nothing, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Do you have code files you can share?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 yeah sure, css here http://pastebin.com/mMw6A3Z9, html here http://pastebin.com/QuD4z0ss

Comment: Pastebin in not enough. We need a [mcve] with the **minimal** CSS **and HTML** included (not just linked) **in the question itself**.

Comment: @Oriol, I'm sorry. I really tought you couldn't do it. Thanks for the information, I removed the comment to prevent it to mislead others :)

Answer (score 1):

From the look of your code, this may be a better solution

```css
.img {display:none; opacity:0;}
.img.active {display:block; opacity: 1;}
```

```html
<div class="caption">
  <ul>
    <li class="img active">Image 1</li>
    <li class="img">Image 2</li>
    <li class="img">Image 3</li>
    <li class="img">Image 4</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

This leaves your mark up cleaner and more semantic. It is also important to get an understanding of [CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

To me, using `active` as an id feels wrong.

`!important` is normally used as an [absolute desperate last measure](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/), most cased can normally be overcome by understanding and leveraging specificity.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it almost does the job, I added your suggestions but when I change the image the text does not dissapear, please take a look http://www.g3eo.com/#!/page_Products. This stopped working when I started using CSS sprite, before that `id=active` worked normally. I also think there is something funny with that active and id.

Comment: There is a fair bit of code on that page to dig through, and you're actively developing it. Can you provide a small self-contained example of what you are trying to achieve on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your inline css into `<style></style>`tags:

```
<li class="img1"></li>
<style>
.img1 {
    opacity:1!important;
    display:block!important;
}
</style>
```

Edit: To make something disappear, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(.someclass).onClick(function(){
        $(.imgwhatever).hide();
    });
});
```

in a Javascript/Jquery file.

Edit: Add this line as well: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`. This makes it so jquery works.

Comment: thanks, now works, the problem is that this changes with other images, so there is img2, img3, etc. Removing !important does not solve the issue. Here is the live example `view-source:http://www.g3eo.com/#!/page_Products`, line 312

Comment: First of all, you can't contain lists in `<p>` elements.

Comment: Can't you just add classes: `.img2 {stuff} .img3 {stuff} ...`?

Comment: adding classes work, but it does not hide the previous one (eg. img1), that's the issue. If style is removed, the `img1` does not show up.

Comment: Do you mean hide like make disappear? If so, then there is some jquery you can do.

Comment: yeah dissapear, that's the idea. Jquery sounds hard to implement, does it?

Comment: putting `<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$(.img1).onClick(function(){$(.img1).hide();});});</script>` at the end of the `body` does nothing, is that correct?